# Can I do a partial revert in GIT

Tags: git

Is it possible to revert only a single file or certain changes in a file in multi file commit?

**Full story**
I committed a bunch of files. A number of commits later someone who will remain nameless (JACK!!!) copied a file into his repository and committed several files, overwriting some of the changes I did. I want to revert the one file that got clobbered or better yet, go in and revert two changes in that file. This will have to be a separate revert commit since it was pulled and pushed.

Comment: Brian got me on the right track. I ended up using git add --patch then using the edit function within patch to get what I wanted.

Comment: I'm pretty late to the game, but I think I found [the "right" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23401018/470844).

Comment: @ntc2 Oddly, the accepted answer worked for me much better than the one you linked - it created merge conflicts for me to resolve, instead of just failing to apply patches.

Comment: @liridayn Did you read my whole answer? In the "variations" section I claim that adding `--3way` results in merge conflicts instead of failure to apply patches.

Comment: Also discussed on the [Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAGP6POLx0+OhMJ9oqmK8R9Lq7tppC258NWHNFhqXMbO9smXd+w@mail.gmail.com/T/#u).

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can revert the commit without creating a new one by adding the `--no-commit` option. This leaves all the reverted files in the staging area.

From there, I'd perform a mixed reset (the default for reset) to un-stage the files, and add in the changes I really wanted.  Then, commit, (you can add and commit more files if you want multiple commits), and finally, checkout the current directory to wipe out any uncommitted and un-staged modifications resulting from the `revert`. For an example workflow:

```bash
git revert <sha-of-bad-commit> --no-commit
git reset   # This gets them out of the staging area

# ...edit bad file to look like it should, if necessary

git add <bad-file>
git commit
git checkout . # This wipes all the undesired reverts still hanging around in the working copy
```

Comment: After the soft reset, you can also do `git add -p` to start an interactive session that allows you to selectively add chunks of files, instead of entire files. (There's also `git reset -p` to selectively unstage changes. Good to know, but probably not what you want in this scenario.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for: Revert into working copy, select hunks interactively, commit. You deserve a big,salty man-smooch for that :*

Comment: Another solution inspired by this one would be to `revert`, `reset`, `stash -p` (stash "cancels that I don't want to actualy make"), `add` the rest, `commit`

Comment: `git reset` is shorthand for `git reset --mixed HEAD`.  So isn't the `git reset` shown by this answer actually a `--mixed` reset, not a `--soft` reset, as stated, since mixed is the default per `git help reset`?  That is, a mixed reset both resets the commit that the current branch is pointing to (to the commit represented by `HEAD` in this case), as well as removes files from the index/staging area (i.e. updates the staging area with whatever snapshot `HEAD` now points to, *Pro Git*, pg. 217).  I confirm `git reset --soft` doesn't unstage files. If someone can confirm, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @StéphanKochen it's actually a mixed reset, see my other comment

Answer (score 97):

You can interactively apply old version of a file using the `checkout` command.

For example, if you know the `COMMIT` where the code to add back was removed, you can run the following command:

```
git checkout -p COMMIT^ -- FILE_TO_REVERT
```

Git will prompt you to add back the hunks that are missing from the current version of the file. You can use `e` to create a patch of the change before applying it back.

Comment: Very useful if you want to revert part of file only! Basically, to get chunks from head, `git checkout -p path/to/file`

Comment: This isn't really useful if the commit isn't the latest or almost latest. It won't offer to reverse the contents of that commit specifically, it will offer to reverse all changes since the parent of the commit.

Answer (score 44):

You can just manually check out the old, good contents of the files you want to revert using `git checkout`. For instance, if you want to revert `my-important-file` to the version it was in the version `abc123`, you can do

```
git checkout abc123 -- my-important-file
```

Now you have the old contents of `my-important-file` back, and can even edit them if you feel like, and commit as usual to make a commit which will revert the changes that he made. If there are only some parts of his commit that you want to revert, use `git add -p` to select only a few hunks from the patch that you are committing.

Comment: This is not a `revert`, you're just taking back an old version of the file. A proper `revert` will remove the bad commit modifications within the file, even if it has been modified several times since that bad commit, and you don't want to loose **those** modifications.

Comment: Totor, see my answer. You can use '-p' to save modifications. The answer is very close to this one actually.

Comment: Or you can combine this into `git checkout -p`.

Answer (score 35):

I found a way to do this on the Git mailing list:

```
git show <commit> -- <path> | git apply --reverse
```

Source: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Revert-a-single-commit-in-a-single-file-td6064050.html#a6064406

## Variations

That command fails (causing no changes) if the patch does not apply cleanly, but with `--3way` you instead get conflicts which you can then resolve manually (in this case [Casey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664248/470844) might be more practical):

```
git show <commit> -- <path> | git apply --reverse --3way
```

You can also use this to partially revert multiple commits, e.g.:

```
git log -S<string> --patch | git apply --reverse
```

to revert files with changes matching `<string>` in any commit.  This is exactly what I needed in my use case (a few separate commits introduced similar changes to different files, along with changes other files in unrelated ways that I did not want to revert).

If you have `diff.noprefix=true` set in your `~/.gitconfig` then you need to add `-p0` to the `git apply` command, e.g.

```
git show <commit> -- <path> | git apply -p0 --reverse
```

Comment: This answer is much better than the accepted one: "better yet, go in and revert two changes in that file".

Comment: I wanted to revert only part of a commit, so I did: **(1)** `git show ... > foo.txt` **(2)** edit `foo.txt` to remove the diffs I wanted not to revert **(3)** `git apply --reverse foo.txt` to revert the diffs still listed in `foo.txt`.

Comment: Adding --binary --full-index to git show part could also be a useful variation

Comment: This even works if you pass a pattern in `<path>`. Beautiful!