# Git undo partial changes to a file

Tags: git, merge, undo

How do I undo a part of the changes applied to a file that happened a while ago.  I have the following commits and the accidental changes happened between `A` and `B` to `file.txt`:

```
...--A--B--...
```

I have a diff patch of the file in `file.txt-B-A.patch` which reverts **all** changes.
However I only want to undo **certain changes** in `file.txt`, much like manually picking changes in a merge conflict. Is there a way to do so without modifying the patch file?

Comment: See also [Q: Can I do a partial revert in GIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669358/can-i-do-a-partial-revert-in-git).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's another way to do this that doesn't require the patch file at all.

The problem happened going from `A` to `B`, so first revert the changes in `B` but don't automatically commit.

```
$ git revert --no-commit <commit hash of B>
```

The changes that `git revert` would do are staged. Unstage them.

```
$ git reset HEAD
```

Next, interactively go through `file.txt` and stage only the changes you want to keep.

```
$ git add --patch file.txt
```

Only the reverts you selected are now staged. Commit them.

```
$ git commit
```

Finally, clean up the unstaged leftovers from `git revert`.

```
$ git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 13):

Many git commands have the `-p` option ("patch") or `-i` ("interactive") to do something partially. For arbitrary diffs I don't think this is supported, but you can apply the patch and then selectively undo unstaged changes using `git checkout -p -- <path(s)>`, e.g. `git checkout -p -- .` if you're at the top level of the repo.

Comment: but that is on a per file basis, however I would like to undo particular changes inside a single file (maybe that is not a git related per se).

Comment: So, apply the patch and then `git checkout -p -- file.txt`; the net result is that you have applied the patch to file.txt except for the things you undid in the second step. If that's not what you want, I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: The patch will include ALL changes between the files, and not just a part of it. Let's say I only want to undo changes that happened after line 500 in my file.

Comment: Yes, and that's what the second step "fixes". You can choose which changes you don't want to have after all. The command prompts you for each hunk of the patch whether you want to undo it.